# Why is there no "views" column in the Answers section of profiles?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

You can sort both questions you've asked and answers you've given by the number of views, but you can't actually see the number of views in the answer section.

Comment: How do you split the views from the question and its answers?

Comment: Look at your profile page--you have a list of questions you've asked,  questions you've answered, your votes, tags, and badges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Answers section does need some love. The formatting just looks kind of weak, and probably should include the data used to sort (dates, views).

The distinct between 'recent' and 'newest' sorts isn't terribly clear either (for both Questions & Answers). I assume one applies to the origin date, and the other to ongoing activity? Very confusing.